# Image resize, crop and upload to server and database

Tags: php, image, user-interface, upload

I am trying to make an avatar image upload for user, where they can crop the avatar too. At this moment I'm able to save the normal size of the image on my server, but when I am trying to crop that image it's like the coordinates are fixed, I think on the left top corner.
Here is my form in **accounts.php**:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#change-profile">
    <div id="profile-result">
        <?php if (file_exists('accounts/images/' . $session_username . '.jpg')): ?>
            <img src="<?php echo 'accounts/images/' . $session_username . '.jpg'; ?>" alt="" class="thumb-lg img-circle" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;">
        <?php else: ?>
            <img src="accounts/images/default.png" alt="" class="thumb-lg img-circle"  style="width: 120px; height: 120px;">
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="change-profile">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="" style="background: #fff; padding: 10px;">
            <div class="ajax-response" id="loading"></div>
            <h4 class="m-t-5 m-b-5 ellipsis">Change profile</h4>
            <div class="image-full-div" style="width: 70%;">
                <form action="crop.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return checkCoords();">
                    <p>Image: <input name="image" id="fileInput" type="file" /></p>
                    <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
                    <input name="upload" type="submit" value="Upload" />
                </form>

                <p><img id="filePreview" style="display:none;"/></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my **crop.php** file for the upload:

```
<?php
//if upload form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["upload"])){
    //get the file information
    $error = '';
    $fileName = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $fileTmp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $fileType = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
    $fileSize = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
    $fileExt = substr($fileName, strrpos($fileName, ".") + 1);

    //specify image upload directory
    $largeImageLoc = 'accounts/images/'.$fileName;
    $thumbImageLoc = 'accounts/images/thumb/'.$fileName;

    //check file extension
    if((!empty($_FILES["image"])) && ($_FILES["image"]["error"] == 0)){
        if($fileExt != "jpg" && $fileExt != "jpeg" && $fileExt != "png"){
            $error = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG & PNG files are allowed.";
        }
    }else{
        $error = "Select a JPG, JPEG & PNG image to upload";
    }

    //if everything is ok, try to upload file
    if(strlen($error) == 0 && !empty($fileName)){
        if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $largeImageLoc)){
            //file permission
            chmod ($largeImageLoc, 0777);

            //get dimensions of the original image
            list($width_org, $height_org) = getimagesize($largeImageLoc);

            //get image coords
            $x = (int) $_POST['x'];
            $y = (int) $_POST['y'];
            $width = (int) $_POST['w'];
            $height = (int) $_POST['h'];

            //define the final size of the cropped image
            $width_new = $width;
            $height_new = $height;

            //crop and resize image
            $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width_new,$height_new);


            switch($fileType) {
                case "image/gif":
                    $source = imagecreatefromgif($largeImageLoc); 
                    break;
                case "image/pjpeg":
                case "image/jpeg":
                case "image/jpg":
                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($largeImageLoc); 
                    break;
                case "image/png":
                case "image/x-png":
                    $source = imagecreatefrompng($largeImageLoc); 
                    break;
            }

            imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,$x,$y,$width_new,$height_new,$width,$height);

            switch($fileType) {
                case "image/gif":
                    imagegif($newImage,$thumbImageLoc); 
                    break;
                case "image/pjpeg":
                case "image/jpeg":
                case "image/jpg":
                    imagejpeg($newImage,$thumbImageLoc,90); 
                    break;
                case "image/png":
                case "image/x-png":
                    imagepng($newImage,$thumbImageLoc);  
                    break;
            }
            imagedestroy($newImage);

            //remove large image
            //unlink($imageUploadLoc);

            //display cropped image
            echo 'CROP IMAGE:<br/><img src="'.$thumbImageLoc.'"/>';
        }else{
            $error = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }else{
        //display error
        echo $error;
    }
}
?>
```

And my Javascript file:

```
//set image coordinates
function updateCoords(im,obj){
    $('#x').val(obj.x1);
    $('#y').val(obj.y1);
    $('#w').val(obj.width);
    $('#h').val(obj.height);
}

//check coordinates
function checkCoords(){
    if(parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
    alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //prepare instant image preview
    var p = $("#filePreview");
    $("#fileInput").change(function(){
        //fadeOut or hide preview
        p.fadeOut();

        //prepare HTML5 FileReader
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("fileInput").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            p.attr('src', oFREvent.target.result).fadeIn();
        };
    });

    //implement imgAreaSelect plugin
    $('img#filePreview').imgAreaSelect({
        // set crop ratio (optional)
        //aspectRatio: '2:1',
        onSelectEnd: updateCoords
    });
});
```

[This is my image with the coordinates but I'm not sure because the normal size of the image is 1920/1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDubE.png)

[And this image is after I press upload button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH7D4.png)